# Injecting ILogger

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm trying to inject ILogger interface in my application.

This is how I register it in my App.xaml.cs

```
    DependencyService.Register<ILogger>();
```

And in my view-model I'm trying to get it from the container like this

```
     _logger = DependencyService.Get<ILogger>();
```

But I get null in return and this error

**Default constructor not found for type Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger"**

If I remember correct in asp .net core this is how I was registering ILogger

Comment: `DependencyService` requires that your class have a default (empty) constructor.

Comment: Aren’t you mIssing the class you want to register? You are declaring the interface in the register method.

Comment: Then I should implement ILogger?

Comment: Either this or use any existing logging provider eg. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#logging-providers

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#bilp - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#third-party-logging-providers